# Accessing array in if statement significantly decreases performance

Tags: arrays, c, performance, sdl, sdl-2

So I am trying to implement a rendering function for my array of squares. Array represents output of raycasted hitbox of explosion:

[image: Algorithm output]

For drawing I am using SDL2 library, but drawing one rect at a time is too demanding. So I came across texture streaming. Now I have two `for` loops that are going through my array containing hitbox information. Array is on stack is type of `char` (`ExplosionGrid`) and represents rectangles on screen, if rectangle is hit by collision it stores `1` if not then it stores `0` and if there is an obstacle it stores `2`.

I have two code examples.

1. No performance impact:

```
SDL_LockTexture(ExplTextFast, NULL, &ExplSurfFast->pixels, &ExplSurfFast->pitch);
            int StartRendX = (int)((crosshair.x + 10) / 6);
            int StartRendY = (int)((crosshair.y + 10) / 6);
            for (int i = 0; i < 65; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 65; j++)
                {
                        if (1)
                        {
                            *(((int*)ExplSurfFast->pixels) + j + (i * 65)) = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            *(((int*)ExplSurfFast->pixels) + j + (i * 65)) = 0xFFFFFFFF;
                        }
                }
            }
            SDL_UnlockTexture(ExplTextFast);
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer1, ExplTextFast, NULL, &DrawingRectExpl);
```

It just changes pixel data in surface.

2. Huge performance drop:

```
SDL_LockTexture(ExplTextFast, NULL, &ExplSurfFast->pixels, &ExplSurfFast->pitch);
            int StartRendX = (int)((crosshair.x + 10) / 6);
            int StartRendY = (int)((crosshair.y + 10) / 6);
            for (int i = 0; i < 65; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 65; j++)
                {
                        if (ExplosionGrid[i][j] == 1)
                        {
                            *(((int*)ExplSurfFast->pixels) + j + (i * 65)) = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            *(((int*)ExplSurfFast->pixels) + j + (i * 65)) = 0xFFFFFFFF;
                        }
                }
            }
            SDL_UnlockTexture(ExplTextFast);
            SDL_RenderCopy(renderer1, ExplTextFast, NULL, &DrawingRectExpl);
```

As you can see the number of iterations in very small. But at the same time it uses 20% of cpu. And the first example uses `0.0xx%`.
Those methods are called hundred times a second. But still the number of iterations is very small.

If I use `if (rand()%2)` the performance is good. But it seems like accessing an array on the stack and using it in an `if` statement causes performance problems.

I tried profiling my code and found out that array inside of if statements was crushing my performance, but i can not wrap my head around it why.

Comment: Putting `ExplosionGrid[1][1]` into a variable (outside of the loops) and using that variable for your `if` statement (inside the loops) would eliminate the array accesses.

Comment: Better yet, put the result of `ExplosionGrid[1][1] == 1` into a variable, and use that in your `if`.  The equality comparison would then only occur once.

Comment: But i would like to use ExplosionGrid[i][j] == 1. This [1][1] was just for demonstration. I am going to edit it for better understanding, sorry.

Comment: The 'if' was probably optimised out entirely in the first case leaving only ..(expression) = 0;. Why don't i and j go to 65 in the second case? You probably should compare like with like.

Comment: As i eddited even if i use "if (rand()%2)" in if argument. Performance is great. Second loops dont go to 65 just because while i was profiling it i noticed that evet if i and j go to 2 so number of itterations is 4 (number of itterations) * 100 (fps count). It still has bad performance, which is weird because number of itterations is small.

Comment: You probably should have a variable like ix65 = i * 65 calculated outside the j loop then used inside the j loop. Your ExplosionGrid array might be too big for your L1d cache. What CPU are you using? What type are the elements?

Comment: In your first example the compiler might even eliminate your loops and use `memset()` or similar, since the loop bounds are constant and the `if` always has the same outcome.

Comment: "Array is on stack" ... does it change if you put the array on heap, make it global? Make it `static`, `volatile`, *read-only* (through `const` argument)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more profiling i have found that problem is not in rendering. But in algorithm computing `ExplosionGrid` array. But without rendering it was not used anywhere so compiler did not iclude it.
But with just one access to that array compiler compiled that algorithm and it ruined performance.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following make a difference?

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 65; i++)
        {
            char *temp = ExplosionGrid[i]; // <== new pointer
            for (int j = 0; j < 65; j++)
            {
                    if (*temp++ == 1)      // <== use pointer
                    {
```

Comment: No difference. Still 20% cpu usage. Even if i and j goes just to 2... so 4 itterations.

Comment: If iterating 2x2 has the same performance as 65x65, this suggests the body of the loop is irrelevant. Something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a reduce the number of mispredicted branches by computing the call value from `ExplosionGrid[i][j]` instead of testing and branching:

```
SDL_LockTexture(ExplTextFast, NULL, &ExplSurfFast->pixels, &ExplSurfFast->pitch);

    int StartRendX = (int)((crosshair.x + 10) / 6);
    int StartRendY = (int)((crosshair.y + 10) / 6);
    for (int i = 0; i < 65; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 65; j++)
        {
            *(((unsigned int *)ExplSurfFast->pixels) + j + (i * 65)) = -(ExplosionGrid[i][j] != 1);
        }
    }
    SDL_UnlockTexture(ExplTextFast);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer1, ExplTextFast, NULL, &DrawingRectExpl);
```

Comment: This did not help but thanks.

Comment: Will `foo != 1` not create a comparison and branch?

Comment: I have tried `*(((int*)ExplSurfFast->pixels) + j + (i * 65)) = ExplosionGrid[i][j] * 0x0000FFFF;` as well but it is still weird that only 4 itterations can create 20% cpu usage. But 65*65 is still a small number.